# Dynamic Referencing formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an excel project involving music. I have all the different notes defined in a sheet of constants and want to show scales on the main sheet. These are runs of the constants in different orders.

**For example:**

If in one sheet I defined  A - B - C - D

I want to be able to dynamically fill lists with the last element looping back to the first (like a list with the last element having a reference to the first element). Example output below.

```
Root   Scale

A   A - B - C - D
B   B - C - D - A
C   C - D - A - B
D   D - A - B - C
```

The logic in pseudocode

```
if (lookup == 0)
   cell value = lookup - num constants defined //loop back around
else (cell value = lookup value)
```

I've tried to implement this with something like

```
=if constants!A2 = 0, <Loop around and fetch the equivalent Value>, <constants!A2>)
```

If possible I'd love to make the entire thing dynamic

```
=if constants!$[Row()][Column()] = 0, <Loop around and fetch the equivalent Value>, <constants!$[Row()][Column()]>)
```

Neither of these work as the syntax is wrong but I hope they communicate the idea effectively.

Comment: How are your constants defined? i.e. one per row (on the same column), or one per column (on the same row),  or all of them in one cell separated by `-`? A formula is possible if you use one the first two options.

Comment: One per column in a row. 

I figured it would make increment within for formula on another sheet easier, they're just text of letters (C C# D etc.)

Comment: `offset` would assist here,something along these lines as a formula `offset(b1,0,0,1,8)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the first column of the scale is always the same as the root then after that (starting in C2 in my case)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$D$2,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$D$2,0)+1),Sheet2!$A$2)
```

where the notes of the scale (A,B,C,D) are in sheet2!a2:d2.

So it tries to get the next note in sequence, but if that fails it goes back to the first one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator `MOD` is perfect to assist cyclic rotations.

In the diagram below, I have the constants on row 2. From Cell `A11` and up, I enter constants where the rotation should start from (the green area). Then I enter the follwoing formula at `B11` and copy/paste in the yellow area:

```
=INDEX($2:$2,1+MOD(MATCH($A11,$2:$2)+COLUMN(B11)-COLUMN($C11),COUNTA($2:$2)))
```

[image]

You can transfer the section to another sheet and adjust the cell addresses, and by adding `Constants!` in front of `2:2`. Notice also that the formula adjusts automatically with the number of constants...

Comment: I love this solution but I'm having a problem with your 2nd argument. 
The second parameter for the match function doesn't seem to evaluate when you reference a range in another sheet. So when I go 

MATCH($B$4,Constants!$B$1:$M$1) The 2nd part evaluates to nothing and it doesn't find a match, I tested it in a single sheet and it works as expected.

Comment: @Eogcloud it is not due to referencing another sheet, but to the layout you are actually using which is probably different than what I assumed. So `B4` is the cell where you enter the first constant? Inportantly, *does it count* in the generated sequence, or it will be repeated at `C4`?